# Spring Integration http outbound-gateway and UTF-8

Tags: java, xml, utf-8, spring-integration

I'm trying to use Spring Integration to load a multilingual XML file from the web. Unfortunately, it appears that Spring Integration is treating it as some other form of encoding. Here's the relevant part of my config:

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway id="example"
    request-channel="requests"
    url="http://localhost/test.xml"
    http-method="GET"
    expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
    charset="UTF-8"
    reply-timeout="1234"
    reply-channel="replies"/>
```

The text I retrieve is treated like it's ISO-8859-1. The reason I believe this, is because if I recode and then decode, I get the correct text. Something like this:

```
public void handleReply(String rawXML) {
    String forRealzies = "";
    try {
        String hack1 = URLEncoder.encode(rawXML, "ISO-8859-1");
        forRealzies = URLDecoder.decode(hack1, "UTF-8");
    } catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    // forRealzies now has the properly encoded String
}
```

I'm really hoping I'm doing something wrong in the XML config. Any suggestions?

Comment: The `charset` attribute is only used when converting an outbound String payload to bytes (and to set up the outbound `content-type` header. Is the `content-type` header on the reply correct?

Comment: Hi Gary, I'm seeing text/xml as the content type. (And in my dev environment, it's simply an xml file sitting within my eclipse project.) I should also point out that when I read the file from the filesystem, it gets parsed properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the `charset` on the `content-type`; see [here](http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset).

Comment: Hi Gary, if I had the option, I would set the charset. However, there are a number of sites that simply don't provide the charset. (From the document you referred to: "But there are too many unlabeled documents in other encodings, so browsers use the reader's preferred encoding when there is no explicit charset parameter.") Is there a way to override this value if it's not set? (Stated another way, can I specify the preferred encoding in Spring Integration?)

Comment: I think (I haven't checked) that the default message converter will use the platform's default charset if it's not in the `content-type`. You could configure a custom message converter, or set the `expected-response-type` to `byte[]` and then use an  `<object-to-string-transformer />` with a charset of your choice.